# ExactTarget: colon changed to %3A

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm not sure if this question falls into AMPscript category or if it's more suitable for the Salesforce support but I've got some issues with links and I'm not sure how to fix.

Some URLs I have in an email have ":" but they are changed to "%3A" in browser. i.e.
http://google.com/?eml=eml:blahblah

On click in browser I see:
http://google.com/?eml=eml%3Ablahblah

Is there any way to fix this through code or I should reach to Salesforce support?

Thanks, VD

Comment: That's just basic [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but all URLs must be composed only of ASCII characters.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the URLs are supposed to be tracked through Omniture and I'm afraid they won't get tracked because of that. I don't think it's a requirement for the links to be encoded to work - as a matter of fact if I just paste the links in browser they open the pages without problems, it's only when they go through exacttarget the : changes to %3A

Comment: Have you tested?  I would imagine that Omniture handles encoded URLs just fine.  The Marketing Cloud isn't the only process to encode URLs.